# How to prove this property of floor function?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functions

$
\left\lfloor { - x} \right\rfloor  =  - \left\lfloor x \right\rfloor
$
if $x \in \mathbb{Z}$ and

$ \left\lfloor { - x}\right\rfloor = - \left\lfloor x \right\rfloor -1 $ otherwise

This is an exercise from Tom Apostol's book "Calculus Volume I" section 1.11 number 4. He defined $\left\lfloor x \right\rfloor$ as the greatest integer $\leqslant x$.

I have tried it but I don't get it. Could you help me?.

Comment: Direct from the definition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use that you define $[x]$ such that $[x]\leq x<[x]+1$. Now replace this into all the statements you want to prove.

Comment: Thanks. I was able to prove that with your definiton. However I think, because Apostol's definition is "the greatest integer $\leqslant x$", I must prove $\left[ x \right] \leqslant x < \left[ x \right] + 1$ as a consequence of his definition, and that $\left[ x \right]$ is unique.

Comment: I think saying that $[x]$ is an integer such that $[x]\leq x <[x]+1$ is saying that it is the greatest integer $\leq x$. This is because the next integer is $[x]+1$ and you are saying that this is already strictly greater than $x$.

Answer (score 1):

Let, $x  =  y+z$  where y is an integer number and $1>z>0$. So $y = \left\lfloor x\right\rfloor$.
multiplying both sides of $x  =  y+z$ with -1, we get,

$-x=-y-z$

So $-x<-y$ and the difference between $-y$ and $-x$ is $-z$ where, $-1<z<0$ So, $\left\lfloor -z\right\rfloor=-1$.
$
\left\lfloor { - x} \right\rfloor  = -y-1= - \left\lfloor x \right\rfloor-1
$ as $\left\lfloor {x} \right\rfloor = y$

Answer (score 0):

Lets make 2 cases:
**CASE 1 :**$
\left\lfloor { - x} \right\rfloor  =  - \left\lfloor x \right\rfloor
$
if $x \in \mathbb{Z}$ 
 Whenever we have an Integer inside this function it remains unchanged so bringing the minus sign out is completely legal.

 **CASE 2:**
$ \left\lfloor { - x}\right\rfloor = - \left\lfloor x \right\rfloor -1 $ otherwise.

 We know [-x] = -x - {-x} where{.} denotes the fractional part of x

Take minus common in RHS to get [-x] = -(x+{-x})

Now we know that {-x} = 1-{x} when x is not an integer (By the very nature of{.}) 

 Now substitute this to the above equation to get the desired result.

Comment: I think the statement  {-x} = 1-{x} should be proved. It does not seem different than writing without proof $\left\lfloor { - x}\right\rfloor = - \left\lfloor x \right\rfloor -1$ by the very nature of the floor function.